# what does it mean `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers' was changed outside of `dotspacemacs/layers'?

Tags: spacemacs

My spacemacs is 0.200.3@25.1.1

I got a warning when launching spacemacs every time, how to fix this?

> Warnings:
>                                             - `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers' was changed outside of`
>   dotspacemacs/layers'.

Answer (score 7):

I have got the same warning after update to the recent version 0.200.5 but it was caused by following line in my .spacemacs, which was in `dotspacemacs/user-config` function:

```
  (setq-default dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
            '((auto-completion :variables
                               auto-completion-enable-snippets-in-popup t)))
```

In your case, please find all occurrences of `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` variable in your config and move them into `dotspacemacs/layers` function in .spacemacs file.

As I understand, now Spacemacs requires to define `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` variable only once in `dotspacemacs/layers` function.

Comment: I have no other dotspacemacs-configuration-layers in ~/.spacemacs file.

Comment: Then it seems some layer in your config hijacks your `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` variable.